# Python: What does >>= do?

Tags: python, operators, python-2.x

I'm learning python and I stumbled upon something I don't understand.

For instance:

```
x = 50

while x:
    print(x)
    x >>= 1
```

Outputs:

```
50
25
12
6
3
1
```

So I infer that it divides by two and rounds to the left if it's not an integer or something similar.

But when I change it to x >>= 3 for instance the output is:

```
50
6
```

Can someone please explain what >>= does?

If so, what are useful applications of this kind of operator.

Comment: `>>=` is the same to `>>` as `+=` to `+`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`>>=` is the [augmented assignment statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements) for the [`>>` right-shift operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations). For immutable types such as `int` it is *exactly* the same thing as:

```
x = x >> 1
```

right-shifting the bits in `x` one step to the right.

You can see what it does if you print the binary representation of `x` first:

```
>>> x = 50
>>> format(x, '08b')
'00110010'
>>> x >>= 1
>>> format(x, '08b')
'00011001'
>>> x = 50
>>> x >>= 3
>>> format(x, '08b')
'00000110'
>>> x
6
```

Each shift to the right is equivalent to a floor division by 2; 3 shifts thus is as if `x` was divided by 2 to the power 3, then floored to an integer.

The complementary operator is the left-shift `<<` operator, multiplying the left-hand integer by 2; it is a binary power-of-two operator:

```
>>> x = 6
>>> format(x, '08b')
'00000110'
>>> x <<= 3
>>> x
48
>>> format(x, '08b')
'00110000'
```

Augmented assignment operators can differ in behaviour when applied to *mutable* types such as a list object, where the operation can take place *in-place*. For example, `listobj += [1, 2, 3]` will alter `listobj` itself, not create a new list object, as if `listobj.extend([1, 2, 3])` was called.

Comment: Nice note about immutable types.

Answer (score 4):

**This is [augmented assignment](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-augmented_assignment_stmt) with the [right shift operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations).**

`x >>= 1` is shorthand for `x = x >> 1`.

`x >>= k` divides by `2**k` (i.e. `2` raised to the `k`-th power).

Thus, `x >>= 3` is the integer division by eight.

Answer (score 4):

It's the binary right shift operator.
For example,
if you have `0100b`, and  you do: `0100b >> 2`, then as a result you will have the number `0001b` (you've shifted the one two positions to the right).